# WSL, Docker: cannot see mounted volume contents

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

While following [this tutorial](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/docker-tutorial-for-beginners/video/part-2-docker-volumes-volumes) one should be able to see the contents of a volume. For example, here's the expected result:

```
    $ sudo ls -la /var/lib/docker/volumes

    total 744
    drwx------ 57 root root 131072 Sep  2 20:52 .
    drwx--x--x 12 root root   4096 Sep  2 09:06 ..
    drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Sep  2 20:52 crv
```

With Docker on Windows (and [installed in WSL](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly)) instead I get:

> ls: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/volumes/crv/_data': No such file or
>   directory

```
george@gwb-10:/mnt/g/Documents/workspace/docker$ docker volume create crv
crv
george@gwb-10:/mnt/g/Documents/workspace/docker$ docker inspect crv
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2018-04-23T13:12:08Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/crv/_data",
        "Name": "crv",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
george@gwb-10:/mnt/g/Documents/workspace/docker$ sudo ls -la /var/lib/docker/volumes
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/volumes': No such file or directory
```

Comment: You are running docker on window? You have to check with the folder mouted with window host folder

Comment: @JinnaBalu I don't understand your comment. The above was generated while using Bash for Windows (WSL).  In the Windows directory `G:\Documents\workspace\docker` I executed the command `wsl`, which puts me in the Linux enviroment. While in that directory I entered the commands as seen above. What is it about that approach that fails to see the contents of the `.../volumes` command? Or, what environment and sequence of commands would allow contents of `.../volumes` to be seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results, of a sort.  I do not understand the syntax, but it is clear a semblance of the expected results exist:

PowerShell:

```
G:\Documents\workspace\docker> docker run --rm -v /var/lib/docker/volumes:/data alpine ls /data
crv
metadata.db
G:\Documents\workspace\docker> docker run --rm -v /var/lib/docker/volumes/crv:/data alpine ls /data
_data
```

WSL:

```
george@gwb-10:/mnt/g/Documents/workspace/docker$ docker.exe run --rm -v /var/lib/docker/volumes:/data alpine ls /data
crv
metadata.db
george@gwb-10:/mnt/g/Documents/workspace/docker$ docker.exe run --rm -v /var/lib/docker/volumes/crv:/data alpine ls /data
_data
```